# Click child anchor scroll to parent html element single page in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, components, innerhtml

I am new to angular 8 & created SPA(single page application), For menu bar separate component and that included inside home component. Whenever menu item clicked(Anchor element), it should scroll to about/contact element section, but I tried few solutions, but not able to scroll. Mainly parent elements are not accessible.

> home.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>

....

<section #aboutus>About us details</section>

....

<section #contact>Contact form section</section>
```

> header.component.html

```
<ul>
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a (click)="navigateTo('aboutus')" ><strong>ABOUT</strong></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a (click)="navigateTo('contact')" ><strong>Contact us</strong></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

> header.component.ts

```
navigateTo(element: string) {
   document.querySelector(''+element+'').scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

I am getting an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null

It will be great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3fora?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

home.component.html

```
<app-header (Navigate)="navigateTo($event)"></app-header>
```

home.component.ts

```
  @ViewChild("aboutus", { static: false }) aboutus;
  @ViewChild("contact", { static: false }) contact;

  navigateTo(element: string) {
    this[element].nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }
```

header.component.ts

```
  @Output() Navigate = new EventEmitter();

  navigateTo(element: string) {
    this.Navigate.emit(element)
  }
```

header.component.html

```
<ul>
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a (click)="navigateTo('aboutus')" ><strong>ABOUT</strong></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a (click)="navigateTo('contact')" ><strong>Contact us</strong></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry, thanks for the answer,but can you move navigation bar to another component like header.compoenet, because I added header menus to separate component and including inside home.component. then  its not working.

Comment: You need eventemitter to have the same logic

Comment: how any reference please

Comment: Check the demo.

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: One suggestion from you, is this the correct approach to separate out repeated code block in Angular?

Comment: Ya, if your code is repeating, it's better to create child component out of it

Answer (score 2):

1 - Add template reference variables to href tags like:

```
  <a (click)="navigateTo('aboutus')" #aboutus><strong>ABOUT</strong></a>
```

2 - Use ViewChild to get the href:

```
  @ViewChild('aboutus') aboutusLink: ElementRef;
```

3 - In this navigateTo function add the following:

```
  this.aboutusLink.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Avoid using native js selectors in Angular :)

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: just replaced document.querySelector(''+element+'').scrollIntoView(true); to your line along with @ViewChild above the "navigateTo(element)" function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `service` for efficient codding.

```js
// navigate.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NavigateService {
  navigate = new EventEmmiter<string>();
}
```

Now the `HeaderComponent`

```js
// header.component.html

<ul>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a (click)="navigateTo('aboutus')" >
      <strong>ABOUT</strong>
    </a>   
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a (click)="navigateTo('contact')" >
      <strong>Contact us</strong>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

// header.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigateService } from 'services/navigate.service'; // set path correctly

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(private navigateService: NavigateService) {}

  navigateTo(status: string): void {
    this.navigateService.navigate.emit(status);
  }
}
```

And Finally the `HomeComponent`

```js
// home.component.html

<app-header></app-header>
....
<section #aboutus>About us details</section>
....
<section #contact>Contact form section</section>

// home.component.ts

import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigateService } from 'services/navigate.service'; // set path correctly

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
  @ViewChild('aboutus', { static: false }) aboutus: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('contact', { static: false }) contact: ElementRef;

  constructor(private navigateService: NavigateService) {
    this.navigateService.navigate.subscribe((status: string) => {
      this[status].nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    });
  }
}
```

Now you can call the service, where you need to navigate. By using service you can get rid of repeating extra code.